# MQL4 drawing rectangle over price

Tags: object, label, rectangles, mql4

I am trying to write a label in a rectangle over the price in the top left corner of my chart with my custom indicator. I can draw the rectangle and the label fine but I cannot get the order in which they display correct.  The candlestick chart is always at the top and I can switch around the label and the rectangle's orders by using the following code

```
ObjectSetInteger(NULL, "objBackground", OBJPROP_BACK,true);
```

Please help, how do I put the candlesticks at the back, then the rectangle and the label(s) at the the forefront?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make chart not on the foreground and you will see objects on top

```
bool ChartForegroundSet(const bool value,const long chart_ID=0)
  {
   //--- reset the error value
   ResetLastError();
   //--- set property value
   if(!ChartSetInteger(chart_ID,CHART_FOREGROUND,0,value))
    {
     //--- display the error message in Experts journal
     Print(__FUNCTION__+", Error Code = ",GetLastError());
     return(false);
    }
   //--- successful execution
   return(true);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I cannot seem to make it work.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Is your problem fixed? same result can be achieved in chart settings (F8)